# Show two columns with the same name in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview that uses a JOIN. The two of the columns, which are from different tables, have the same name:

```
<asp:GridView ID="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
     DataKeyNames="PK_User" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"
     OnRowDataBound="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_OnRowDataBound">
     <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Organization Team" SortExpression="Name" />
     </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                                            SelectCommand="
                                            SELECT [User].[PK_User]
                                                ,[User].[Name]
                                                ,[OrganizationalTeam].[Name]
                                            FROM [User]
                                            LEFT JOIN [OrganizationalTeam] ON [OrganizationalTeam].[PK_OrganizationalTeam] = [User].[OrganizationalTeamId]
                                            WHERE COALESCE(cast([OrganizationalTeam].[InternalExternal] as varchar(255)), 'null') LIKE @internalExternalParam
                                            GROUP BY [User].[Name]
                                                ,[OrganizationalTeam].[Name]
                                                ,[User].[PK_User]
                                            ">
    <SelectParameters>
          <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="internalExternalParam" DefaultValue="%" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

I am having trouble displaying it. The way I would assume it is done is like follows:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="[OrganizationalTeam].[Name]" HeaderText=" Team Name" SortExpression="[OrganizationalTeam].[Name]" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="[User].[Name]" HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="[User].[Name]" />
```

This is causing the following error:

User is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table DefaultView.

How do I present two columns from different tables with the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the column is actually `Name` for both, my suggestion would be to use an alias on them to distinguish between the data from each table:

```
SELECT [User].[PK_User]
    ,[User].[Name] as UserName
    ,[OrganizationalTeam].[Name] as OrganizationalTeamName
FROM [User]
LEFT JOIN [OrganizationalTeam] ON [OrganizationalTeam].[PK_OrganizationalTeam] = [User].[OrganizationalTeamId]
WHERE COALESCE(cast([OrganizationalTeam].[InternalExternal] as varchar(255)), 'null') LIKE @internalExternalParam
GROUP BY [User].[Name]
    ,[OrganizationalTeam].[Name]
```